# Sharp vs. tight

Tags: inequality, terminology, order-theory

What is the difference between a "sharp bound" and a "tight bound"? Are the two adjectives synonyms in mathematical prose? Otherwise, when would you use one and when the other?

Very basic example just to give some context: the quantity $\|a\| \|b\|$ is a sharp/tight bound for $a\cdot b$. But this example might be insufficient, especially if there are nuances in meaning: I am interested in all usages of the two terms when dealing with inequalities / bounds / estimates. I do realize that there might be no exact mathematical definition of these terms.

Comment: Can you give examples of either being used in context?  In the contexts in which I have encountered these phrases, they are synonymous, but they are also not mathematically defined (usually), and are just an expositional flourish, meaning, roughly "this is the best possible estimate".

Comment: @XanderHenderson Done, I hope this is enough.

Comment: I would say that a "tight" bound usually means a very good bound on something, while a "sharp" bound means the best possible bound. Thus, "tight" may be a matter of opinion, while "sharp" is a precise mathematical statement.

Comment: @DanAsimov Please do not use comments to answer the question.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I was more asking for examples from specific texts.  What to the authors who are using these terms mean by them?  It would help to see them in context, "in the wild".

Comment: Can we say: $e$ is a tight bound of $(1 + 1/n)^n$, but not a sharp bound? (A sharp bound is a bound if equality occurs at least one $n$. However, there is no integer $n$ such that $(1 + 1/n)^n = e$. Tight bound since no constant $a$ such that $(1 + 1/n)^n \le a < e$. Am I right?)

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that a sharp bound is one that is achieved, which also implies that it cannot be improved (e.g., for an upper bound, no smaller value is an upper bound). A tight bound cannot be improved, but is not necessarily achieved.

For example, $x \leq 1$ is a sharp bound for $x\in [0,1]$, but is only a tight bound on $(0,1)$. On either interval, $x\leq 2$ is neither sharp nor tight, but is still a bound.